# What does it mean - if [ ! -e "$exe" ]; then in bash

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I saw one of the scripts in the linux. I would like to know what does it mean.

```
if [ ! -e "$exe" ]; then
  exe='/path to some file'
fi
```

Comment: What research have you done? Do you understand any of it? (Hint: “`if`” and “`then`” are English words, and mean pretty much the same in bash as they do in English. If you don’t understand English, learning Linux will be somewhat difficult for you.) Where are you stuck?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Comment: Hi I've never worked with shell before, Thus was facing some problem in understanding in it. Now I went through clues and man page and bit of Bash guide. I'm able to understand the statement I've posted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It means "if the value in the variable `exe` does not correspond to an existing name in the filesystem, then set its value to `/path to some file`".

The `[ -e something ]` test tests whether the name `something` exist as the name of a regular file, directory, or as some other type of file.

The `!` negates the sense of the test.

The `if` statement evaluates the command given to it (in this case the command is `[ ! -e "$exe" ]`), and if that command succeeds (in this case, the file does *not* exist), it executes the statements in the `if` statement body (in this case, the assignment to the variable `exe`).

You may read more about various tests by reading the manuals for the `[` or `test` utilities (`man [` or `man test`).

The `if` statement is described in the manual of your shell (e.g. `man bash`). That manual will also describe variables, and variable assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Run `info test` for details:

```
16.3.3 File characteristic tests
--------------------------------

These options test other file characteristics.

‘-e FILE’
     True if FILE exists.

‘-s FILE’
     True if FILE exists and has a size greater than zero.

‘FILE1 -nt FILE2’
     True if FILE1 is newer (according to modification date) than FILE2,
     or if FILE1 exists and FILE2 does not.

‘FILE1 -ot FILE2’
     True if FILE1 is older (according to modification date) than FILE2,
     or if FILE2 exists and FILE1 does not.

‘FILE1 -ef FILE2’
     True if FILE1 and FILE2 have the same device and inode numbers,
     i.e., if they are hard links to each other.
```